# Why isn't my sql query in sqlite/sqlbrite not working with a second condition/multiple WHERE clauses?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, sqlbrite

I have a query for my Sqlite/Brite databse that takes two conditions. One to check for a selected quarter, and another to make sure an action attribute isn't "delete". When I only have the WHERE clause to check for the selected quarter, I get all the data I want. When I add the WHERE clause to check to make sure it doesn't have a "deleted" attribute, nothing comes back. Nothing should have a deleted attribute so all the same data should come back, but it isn't. Why is this?

Heres the function that's causing me the issues

```
 Stream<List<dynamic>> getTransaction() async* {
    List _transaction = [];
    final sessionData = await getSession();
    final db = await initDatabase();
    yield* db.createQuery(
        "transactions",
        where: 'action != "delete" AND transaction_quarter = ? ',
        whereArgs: [sessionData['selected_quarter']]
    ).mapToList((row) => TransModel.Transaction.fromMap(row));
  }
```

Comment: `"deleted"` or `"delete"`? Post sample data to clarify.

Comment: delete. It would be making sure each record doesn't have a 'delete' flag on it. I can post some sample data in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have `"delete"` in your SQL.  I think you'll need `'delete'`.  They are definitely not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass "delete" in args

```
db.createQuery(
        "transactions",
        where: 'action != ? AND transaction_quarter = ? ',
        whereArgs: ["delete", sessionData['selected_quarter']]
    )
```